# Bathtub Resurfacing Options: Pour-on vs. Spray-on

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

I'd like to resurface an old cast iron/porcelain tub, and in my research of professionals I've found they use various products, but two methods of application: pour-on and spray-on.

I'm looking to understand the pros and cons of each methods. It seems that the advantages to pour-on are that it's odorless, thicker, and possibly harder (so maybe it's more durable?); is this correct, and if so, what are the advantages to spray-on?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 2):

Pour-on is great when you have the ability to move the object around and let the liquid flow around and smoothly and evenly cover the entire surface. It's not so great when you have to move and the object stays still. I doubt you'll be spinning the tub around in all different directions unless you'll have it mounted to a spin table. Spraying will probably be your best option since you'll be the one moving, not the tub. You will need more coats when spraying than you would with pour-on but that's just the way it is. You don't want to start the spray on the object or you'll have circles. Start the spray off of the object and then draw it across the surface and off the surface and then continue back.

Comment: TBH, given the size and weight of a cast iron tub, I'd be pretty surprised to find even a _manufacturer_ using a pour on application. That's a _very_ big tilt table to move a full size tub around enough to ensure an even coating. Plus I can only imagine that it would take quite a bit of time to allow the porcelain material to settle/dry sufficiently that it will stay in place prior to firing. Spraying involves only moving an arm (human or robotic) and the material can dry nearly instantly which is handy in a production environment.